# How to convert Markdown headings (## ...) to LaTeX code?

Tags: markdown

I get a Markdown file with sections starting as

```
##sectionN
```

And I would like to use regex (`sed` or `awk`) to convert it to

```
\ditem[sectionN}
```

where `sectionN` takes many different names. I guess that the key is to detect lines starting as `##` and then writing `sectionN` as the argument of `\ditem[]`.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason to roll your own converter instead of using [tools designed for this task](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)?

Comment: I know pandoc. But the question is how to convert from markdown sections (##) to the latex keyword (\ditem[]) for a glossary class.

Comment: @Steve: You mention you'd like to use some regular expression to convert `##sectionN` to `\ditem[sectionN]`... then this has little to do with LaTeX. Unless you want to do this "convertion" in LaTeX. Also, we'd need a little more context if that's the case. For example, is this a stand-alone file containing `##sectionN` markdown and that's it? No other heading markers like `#heading1` or `###heading3`?

Comment: I will explain it better; In the markdown source there are only ## sections. Although, there are some commands starting with '#' but they are tabulated. So, we get lines starting, and starting with double ## to conver.

Answer (score 0):

A regex (depending on what language you use) should work just fine.

for example, in php, run this code:

```
$new_line = preg_replace ( "%\#{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]+)%" , '\\ditem{$1}' , $line );
```

http://ideone.com/umjauU